# Drag&drop event (WM_DROPFILES) in C++ GUI

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a simple application where the user can drag and drop files from outside of the window (usually Explorer) into an area inside of the window. My ultimate purpose is to get the file path to later on process it.

Currently I can drag and drop files into the area but I never receive the WM_DROPFILES event. I have tried with some related functions (DoDragDrop, RegisterDragDrop, CDropSource), but they all have been either impossible to compile or unsuccessful.

Could anyone tell me if I am missing setting any property?

Many thanks in advance

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES,
                TEXT("static"),
                TEXT("Drag and drop your file to this area"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                20, // x
                20, // y
                120, // w
                60, // h
                hwnd, // parent window
                (HMENU) 1, // unique label
                NULL, NULL);
        }
        case WM_DROPFILES:
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Dragged!", "Title", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "WindowClass",
        "MySimpleApp",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        WINDOW_W,
        WINDOW_H,
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not receiving the `WM_DROPFILES` message because you are not subclassing the STATIC control you create to receive messages that are sent to it. You are assuming you can catch the message in the control's *parent* window, but that is not where the message goes. It is sent to the window that you actually drop onto - the STATIC control.

Try this instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, &StaticWndProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DROPFILES: {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Dragged!", "Title", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }
    }
        
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            HWND hStatic = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES,
                TEXT("static"),
                TEXT("Drag and drop your file to this area"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                20, // x
                20, // y
                120, // w
                60, // h
                hwnd, // parent window
                (HMENU) 1, // unique label
                NULL, NULL);
            SetWindowSubclass(hStatic, &StaticWndProc, 0, 0);
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`DoDragDrop()` and `RegisterDragDrop()` (which you *should* be using instead of `WM_DROPFILES`) have nothing to do with receiving `WM_DROPFILES`.

Comment: Smooth good solution! I don't need to do it for CreateWindow() but for CreateWindowEx(), why the difference?? I just do if (uMsg == WM_DROPFILES) { PostMessage(GetParent(hwnd), uMsg, wParam, lParam); in the StaticWndProc() and it all ends up in the same place by case WM_DROPFILES in the main switch set. DragAcceptFiles( hwnd, TRUE ); is not needed, might be different to dialogboxes?

Comment: @JanBergström There is no difference in handling the `WM_DROPFILES` message itself if you use `CreateWindow()` vs `CreateWindowEx()`. But you will need to call `DragAcceptFiles()` if you use `CreateWindow()` instead of `CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, ...)`. However, yes you can certainly forward the message to the parent window if you want, but you will have to use `SendMessage()` instead of `PostMessage()` in that situation, as `PostMessage()` is asynchronous and the `HDROP` which is carried in the `wParam` won't be valid anymore once the original `WM_DROPFILES` handler exits.

Comment: It looks like the default DragAcceptFiles( hwnd, TRUE ); setting is different regarding CreateWindows() TRUE, CreateWindowsEx FALSE and rc-files (FALSE) and by calling DragAcceptFiles( hwnd, TRUE ); them all works, or with FALSE not work. Works with both PostMessage() and SendMessage() but I think you are right, it should be SendMessage().

Comment: @JanBergström `CreateWindow()` is just a wrapper for `CreateWindowEx()`. Accepting files is off by default on ALL windows, you have to either include the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` window style (which `CreateWindow()` doesn't do), or call `DragAcceptFiles()` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing

```
DragAcceptFiles( hwnd, TRUE );
```

Put it just before message loop.

`WM_DROPFILES` fails to correctly transfer data from 32-bit application to 64-bit one. Could be remedied by implementing `IDropTarget` and removing `WM_DROPFILES` handling.

Comment: The `STATIC` window is being created with the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` style, so you don't need to call `DragAcceptFiles()` on it.